# Split string by chunks in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm a newbie to Scala and I'm having trouble trying to split a String by bytes.

Let's say I have a String object of a certain length, the problem is that I need to split and send this string to a consumer in chunks of 1048576 (max) bytes each.

So far, I have tried the following:

```
    val recordDelimiter: String = "\n"
    val recordsBatch: String = dataArray.mkString(recordDelimiter)
    val recordsCount = dataArray.length
    // Send data to stream

    recordsBatch
      .grouped(1048576)
      .foreach(
        chunk =>
          try {
            val putRecordRequest = PutRecordRequest.builder
              .streamName(streamName)
              .data(AWSUtils.toSdkBytes(chunk))
              .partitionKey("partitionKey-1")
              .build
            val response = kinesis.putRecord(putRecordRequest)
            logger.info(s"Records sent to $streamName stream: $recordsCount")
            response.sequenceNumber
          } catch {
            case exception: KinesisException =>
              logger.error("Error occurred while sending data to Kinesis", exception)
              "ERROR"
          } finally {
            kinesis.close()
          }
  )
```

However, I'm obtaining "java.lang.NullPointerException" every time I try to execute the code

Comment: Have you tested this without the AWS bit? Scala is generally pretty good about *not* returning `null`, so I suspect the part that isn't a Scala library is the most suspicious.

Comment: You are closing the `kinesis` after the first chuck so presumably it is invalid for the subsequent chunks.

Comment: You are totally right @Tim, thanks